# Spinner not spinning in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.animationload {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.osahanloading {
    animation: 1.5s linear 0s normal none infinite running osahanloading;
    background: #fed37f none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
}
.osahanloading::after {
    animation: 1.5s linear 0s normal none infinite running osahanloading_after;
    border-color: #85d6de transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    content: "";
    height: 80px;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 80px;
}
@keyframes osahanloading {
0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
    background: #85d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Creative Animated Loading icon in HTML5 CSS3</h2>
        </div>    
        <div class="animationload">
            <div class="osahanloading"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the spinner spinning in Chrome but doesn't spin in IE..I get the spinner but it's kind of static. Can someone have a look at the code and please let me know what's missing here.

For reference here's the code where I got the spinner from
[Link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/OPyjZ#comments)
I have the spinner working perfectly fine but just is not right in IE.

Thanks

Update
Plunker Link [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rairr0AZV9Jb38SCvyPH?p=preview)

Comment: please make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi John..Thanks for your reply..I added the link - http://plnkr.co/edit/rairr0AZV9Jb38SCvyPH?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE wasn't liking the extra params you had on your animation CSS. Removing some of the unnecessary parameters worked.

```css
.animationload {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.osahanloading {
    animation: 1.5s linear infinite osahanloading;
    background: #fed37f none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
}
.osahanloading::after {
    animation: 1.5s linear infinite osahanloading_after;
    border-color: #85d6de transparent;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    content: "";
    height: 80px;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 80px;
}
@keyframes osahanloading {
0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
50% {
    background: #85d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Creative Animated Loading icon in HTML5 CSS3</h2>
        </div>    
        <div class="animationload">
            <div class="osahanloading"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome..Thanks abney317